# Triangulations/quadrangulations of polygon

Tags: regions, polygons

Is there a nice way I can find all possible triangulations (or quadrangulations) of a polygon (say 10-gon)? I want to have all possible diagrams with the diagonals marked (i.e. with unique name). Please suggest me in case there already is a package for such a thing.

Comment: For triangulations take a look at [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/571/) and [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TriangulatingRandomAndRegularPolygons/) and [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolygonTriangulations/).

Comment: @Rohit In particular, the last link would be worth an answer.

Comment: Thanks @RohitNamjoshi. Last link is useful. But I need something more : 1. Vertices are numbered (such that I can identify the diagonals by unique names). 2. Print all possible triangulations for a given polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/571/) is closest to your requirements. To generate labeled vertices, add the following to the `triangulation` function:

```
labels = MapIndexed[Text[Style[First[#2], 10], #1] &, vertices * 1.1];
```

and add it to the `Graphics` argument list

```
Show[Graphics[{poly, edges, labels}]
```

With `size = 5` this is the output:
[image]

I am not sure what you mean by "Print all possible triangulations", but the symbol `edges` is set to a list of the edges for each triangulation.
For `size = 5`, `edges` is

{{{2, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 5}, {3, 5}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {3,5}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 1}}}

You can probably use that to generate the printed form you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I think this is what I want. But somehow I couldn't generate the diagrams from that package. It would be really helpful if you can modify the code and share as a link. Thanks again!

Comment: It's showing some errors, even if I try to run that code unaltered.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/rohit.namjoshi/Published/Triangulations.nb), modified to work on 11.3

Comment: Works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know of any better way of quardangulating a convex polygon?

Comment: @PhysicsMoron Maybe you can use [this](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns).

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.